# Break line inside div but not html

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a "member list" -> multiple pictures with a name on the bottom next to each other. So far i have this:

```
<div class = "members">
    <div class = "member1" style = "display:inline">
        <a href="#"><img src = "head_1.jpg" style = "width: 80px; height: 100px"/></a>
        <a href="#">Member1</a>
    </div>

    <div class = "member2" style = "display:inline">
        <a href="#"><img src = "head_2.jpg" style = "width: 100px; height: 100px"/></a>
        <a href="#">Member 2</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to put a line break between the `<a>` tags but this creates a line break within the html file which causes the next div to appear on the bottom of the previous when I want it to go to the right of it.

I would expect (probably wrongly) putting in the .css file:

```
.members .member1 {
    width: 110px; // or max-width;
}
```

to make the formatting force the second `<a>` tag to appear behind the first in each memeber's `<div>`. How can I achieve what I'm trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.members .member1,.members .member2 {
    width: 110px; // or max-width;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class = "members">
    <div class = "member1">
        <a href="#"><img src = "head_1.jpg" style = "width: 80px; height: 100px"/></a>
        <a href="#">Member1</a>
    </div>

    <div class = "member2">
        <a href="#"><img src = "head_2.jpg" style = "width: 100px; height: 100px"/></a>
        <a href="#">Member 2</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```css
.member1 a{
    display:list-item;
    }
    
    .member2 a{
    display:list-item;
    }
```

```html
<div class = "members">
    <div class = "member1" style = "display:inline">
        <a href="#"><img src = "head_1.jpg" style = "width: 80px; height: 100px"/></a>
        <a href="#">Member1</a>
    </div>

    <div class = "member2" style = "display:inline">
        <a href="#"><img src = "head_2.jpg" style = "width: 100px; height: 100px"/></a>
        <a href="#">Member 2</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Method 1)** Remove `display:inline` of `.member1` and `.member2` and try this:

```
.members .member1, .members .member2 {
    width: 110px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```css
.members .member1, .members .member2 {
    width: 110px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class = "members">
    <div class = "member1">
        <a href="#"><img src = "http://justcuteanimals.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/baby-bear-pictures-cute-animal-pics.jpg" style = "width: 80px; height: 100px"/></a>
        <a href="#">Member1</a>
    </div>

    <div class = "member2">
        <a href="#"><img src = "http://justcuteanimals.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/baby-bear-pictures-cute-animal-pics.jpg" style = "width: 80px; height: 100px"/></a>
        <a href="#">Member 2</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Method 2)** If you need `display:inline`, just add this code:

```
.member1,.member2 {
  float: left;
  width: 110px
}
```

```css
.member1,.member2 {
  float: left;
  width: 110px
}
```

```html
<div class = "members">
    <div class = "member1" style = "display:inline">
        <a href="#"><img src = "http://justcuteanimals.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/baby-bear-pictures-cute-animal-pics.jpg" style = "width: 80px; height: 100px"/></a>
        <a href="#">Member1</a>
    </div>

    <div class = "member2" style = "display:inline">
        <a href="#"><img src = "http://justcuteanimals.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/baby-bear-pictures-cute-animal-pics.jpg" style = "width: 100px; height: 100px"/></a>
        <a href="#">Member 2</a>
    </div>
</div>
```